# Build error using Ant build tool "can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: java, apache, ant

I configured Python to path variable, below is the path variable content

```
%systemroot%\system32;%systemroot%;%systemroot%\system32\wbem;%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;.;c:\program files\tortoisesvn\bin;d:\apache-ant-1.8.3\bin;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;
```

Why I configured Python means, i am creating exe file using ant build and installj

```
<target name="installer.izpack.exe" depends="installer.izpack" description="build release executable izpack installer">
    <exec executable="python" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="${installer.izpack.dir}/utils/wrappers/izpack2exe/izpack2exe.py"/>
        <arg line="--file=${basedir}/installer/EasyIT-installer.jar"/>
        <arg line="--output=${basedir}/installer/EasyIT-installer.exe"/>
        <arg line="--no-upx"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

but when building the app getting below error:

```
installer.izpack.exe:
     [exec] python: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

BUILD FAILED
E:\Java Projects\Spark Projects\EastIT - Copy\build\build.xml:873: exec returned: 2

Total time: 51 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a path with a space in it, e.g.

```
c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin
```

You have to quote the path, like this:

```
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
```

Not 100% sure about Python, but this should work:

> %systemroot%\system32;%systemroot%;%systemroot%\system32\wbem;%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\;"c:\program
>   files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin";.;c:\program
>   files\tortoisesvn\bin;d:\apache-ant-1.8.3\bin;c:\program
>   files\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;%M2_HOME%\bin;"C:\Program
>   Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\";

Notice that some of your path components are shortened to be 8.3 length compatible (they have a ~ in them).  If you don't like the quoting or it doesn't work for Python, you can use the command

> dir /x

to get the shortened version of each path component, e.g. on my system

```
06/12/2012  09:09 AM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
06/12/2012  09:08 AM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

Comment: but the folder name is like that, how can i fix it?

Comment: i changed all paths in environment variables where ever i have program files to PROGRA~1, but still iam getting same issue. do u have any idea

Comment: Then you will have to figure out what the 8.3 filename for those folders is, using dir /x.

Comment: What is your error message?  Is it EXACTLY the same error message?

Comment: Also, what are the values for ${basedir} and ${installer.izpack.dir}?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12472/discussion-between-developer-and-eric-j)

Comment: <property name="installer.izpack.dir" value="C:\Program Files\IzPack"/>
basedir = e:\javaprojects\spark\

Comment: can i change in build file, will that 32 bit convention will work in build.xml

Comment: You have to quote `C:\Program Files\IzPack` or use the short version, which is PROBABLY `C:\PROGRA~1\IzPack` on your system.